# Cannot display AppInsights of AppService in Azure - Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azureportal

When I try to display AppInsights of an App Service in Azure, there is this error "Cannot read property 'id' of null". I tried Chrome and Edge.

I would be grateful for any advice. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is that the Application insights instance is removed(or it may be down). Please check if it still exists or not.

I can repro this issue after removing the application insights instance. Add a screenshot here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have a windows web app. When you create Windows web apps by default you get a number of configurations in your web app

[image]

My best guess would be that one or more of tehse values are missing, so when you try to browse to your application insights account the id can not be found.

I would suggest that you try to recreate the web app, enabling Application Insights and check what configuration values are created. Then try to replicate them.